# Mocha tests don't run when called from an async function

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I'm using Microsoft's vscode-test module to test a VS code extension. I started with their example test runner script from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/e071a73bed498c479bce5e88ed217d88e30a84d8/helloworld-test-sample/src/test/suite/index.ts) - each runner script exports a function `run` which takes no args and returns a `Promise`

```
export function run(): Promise<void> {
    // Create the mocha test
    const mocha = new Mocha({
        ui: 'tdd'
    });
 
    const testsRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

    return new Promise((c, e) => {
        glob('**/**.test.js', { cwd: testsRoot }, (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                return e(err);
            }

            // Add files to the test suite
            files.forEach(f => mocha.addFile(path.resolve(testsRoot, f)));

            try {
                // Run the mocha test
                mocha.run(failures => {
                    if (failures > 0) {
                        e(new Error(`${failures} tests failed.`));
                    } else {
                        c();
                    }
                });
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
                e(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I needed to change this a bit because the latest version of `glob` (9.x) returns a Promise rather than taking a callback, so I rewrote it like this:

```
export async function run (): Promise<void> {
  // Create the mocha test
  const mocha = new Mocha({
    ui: 'tdd',
    color: true
  })
  const testsRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..')
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    glob('**/**.test.js', { cwd: testsRoot })
      .then(files => {
        // Add files to the test suite
        files.map(f => path.resolve(testsRoot, f))
          .forEach(f => mocha.addFile(f))
        // Run the mocha test
        mocha.run((failures: number) => {
          if (failures === 0) {
            resolve()
          } else {
            reject(new Error(`Test failures ${failures}`))
          }
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
        reject(err)
      })
  })
}
```

this works but I was thinking it would be nicer to be able to use `async`/`await` a bit more.

```
export async function run (): Promise<void> {
  // Create the mocha test
  const mocha = new Mocha({
    ui: 'tdd',
    color: true
  })
  const testsRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..')
  const files = await glob('**/**.test.js', { cwd: testsRoot })
  files.map(f => path.resolve(testsRoot, f))
    .forEach(f => mocha.addFile(f))
  // Run the mocha test
  mocha.run((failures: number) => {
    if (failures > 0) {
      throw new Error(`Test failures ${failures}`)
    }
  })
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't run any tests. It definitely reaches the Mocha `suite` definitions but the actual tests are never called. I suspect somewhere a promise is not being resolved before the program as a whole finishes? My understanding was that making a function async causes it to return a promise and throwing is equivalent to calling the reject part of it.

Can anyone help point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You are implicitly skipping the asynchronously executing Mocha suite. There's neither any `await` associated with your call to mocha.run, nor any promisifying of the callback. You probably want something like `const failures = await new Promise<number>((resolve) =>
  mocha.run(resolve)
);
`

Comment: @cefn that seems to have fixed it, thanks. If you make it an answer I'll tick it. It is sort of what I suspected, but I keep thinking that awaiting a new Promise is the same as calling the function directly which of course it isn't.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I've posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implicitly skipping the asynchronously executing Mocha suite. There's neither any await associated with your call to `mocha.run`, nor any promisifying of the callback.

At the crucial point you run the mocha suite you want something like...

```js
const failures = await new Promise<number>((resolve) => mocha.run(resolve));
```